# Downloading PDF as file or stream instead of text

Tags: c#, http, pdf, download, stream

I am downloading a PDF file from SharePoint:

```
 var client2 = new RestClient("https://redacted.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/Shared%20Documents/testfolder/test.pdf')/$value");
 client2.Timeout = -1;
 var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
 request2.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {tokenData.access_token}");
 request2.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
 IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
```

However, `response.Content` is plaintext, like I would've opened the PDF file with a text editor. How do I make it convert to the actual PDF file in order to download it to my PC?
Secondly, how can I add it to a stream? I would need to upload it via a POST request to another function I've made in Azure Functions.

Comment: If your response is actually json then you will will have to convert the applicable section to bytes and save it to a file. If that request is directly returning a file then [see this](https://restsharp.dev/usage/files.html)

Comment: It depends if the file is in the body of the response or a MIME attachment.  HTML has special characters so any data in a body must be a Base64 string. So to get back to binary you need to convert the base64 string to a byte array.  A MIME attachment is after the body and starts with two dashes on a new line.